# NameError: name "" is not defined

Tags: python, mixins, python-class

My code below should print the returned value from the describe method of the customer object to the terminal...but it doesn't. Issue seems to be NameError: name 'price' is not defined.

```
class TicketMixin:
    
    """ Mixin to calculate ticket price based on age """
    def calculate_ticket_price(self, age):
        
        ticket_price = 0
        price = ticket_price
        
        if self.age < 12:
            price = ticket_price + 0
        elif self.age < 18:
            price = ticket_price + 15
        elif self.age < 60:
            price = ticket_price + 20
        elif self.age >= 60:
            price = ticket_price + 10
        return price

class Customer(TicketMixin):
    """ Create instance of Customer """
    def __init__(self, name, age,):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    
    def describe(self):
        return f"{self.name} age {self.age} ticket price is {price}"
        
customer = Customer("Ryan Phillips", 22)
print(customer.describe())
```

Can someone tell what am I missing please?

Comment: `price` is a local variable in `calculate_ticket_price`, not an attribute like `name` or `age`. You have to *call* `calculate_ticket_price` to get the value.

Comment: duh, silly me. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't call `calculate_ticket_price`.

```
def describe(self):
    return f"{self.name} age {self.age} ticket price is {self.calculate_ticket_price(self.age)}"
```

Note that `calculate_ticket_price` can *either* take an `age` argument, in which case it doesn't need to assume `self.age` exists:

```
class TicketMixin:
    
    """ Mixin to calculate ticket price based on age """
    def calculate_ticket_price(self, age):
        
        ticket_price = 0
        price = ticket_price
        
        if age < 12:
            price = ticket_price + 0
        elif age < 18:
            price = ticket_price + 15
        elif age < 60:
            price = ticket_price + 20
        elif age >= 60:
            price = ticket_price + 10
        return price
```

or you can make that assumption and get rid of the `age` parameter altogether:

```
class TicketMixin:
    
    """ Mixin to calculate ticket price based on age """
    def calculate_ticket_price(self):
        
        ticket_price = 0
        price = ticket_price
        
        if self.age < 12:
            price = ticket_price + 0
        elif self.age < 18:
            price = ticket_price + 15
        elif self.age < 60:
            price = ticket_price + 20
        elif self.age >= 60:
            price = ticket_price + 10
        return price
```

Then the body of `describe` would simply omit any explicit argument:

```
def describe(self):
    return f"{self.name} age {self.age} ticket price is {self.calculate_ticket_price()}"
```

---

In the former, note that you don't use `self` *at all* in the definition; that suggests it should be a static method, or just a regular function that can be used by `Customer` without the need for any mix-in class.

Comment: that worked, thank you! getting rid of age was a no-go due to the very strict instructions of my learning challenge in my code bootcamp. I have now called calculate_ticket_price and it did the trick. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Chepner is correct. You have to call **calculate_ticket_price** in your **init** function. The proper syntax is using the super keyword.

Example:

```
class Customer(TicketMixin):
    """ Create instance of Customer """
    def __init__(self, name, age,):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.price = super().calculate_ticket_price(self.age)
    
    def describe(self):
        return f"{self.name} age {self.age} ticket price is {self.price}"
```

You can learn more about the super keyword by clicking [here](https://appdividend.com/2019/01/22/python-super-function-example-super-method-tutorial/).

Comment: Err... `super()` not needed in this case. Just use: `self.calculate_ticket_price(self.age)`. And, fix the other things as well. You will also get `price` not defined. Ok, I see you have fixed `price` now! :-)

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by attaching a variable to calculate_ticket_price since the function returns price.

Comment: didnt even think of using super() - great advice, thanks!

Comment: You don’t need super() here. Just use self.

Comment: You are correct, quamrana. I was trying to mimic Jose's workflow which uses inheritance. If you don't need inheritance then use self.price = self.calculate_ticket_price(self.age) as quamrana suggested.

Comment: No, I’m saying that inheriting from a mixin is just fine and using self works just fine. You don’t need super here. You *do* need super when you are executing a method which overrides a base class method and you want to call the base class method. In that case self won’t work and your only option is to use super.